# Change iframe "src" attribute with jQuery not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, src, attr

In my hrml mockup, I have an iframe to show different contents when click on different thumbnails. For example, when click on thumb1, iframe will display content of page1.html; when click on thumb2, iframe will display content of page2.html. The inline src attribute of the iframe is set to page3.html as the default display:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="page3.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">       </iframe>
```

And the src will be changed on click event by jQuery:

```
$('.thumb1').click(function(){
 $('iframe').attr('src', "page1.html");
});

$('.thumb2').click(function(){
 $('iframe').attr('src', "page2.html");
});

$('.thumb3').click(function(){
 $('iframe').attr('src', "page3.html");
});

$('.thumb4').click(function(){
 $('iframe').attr('src', "page4.html");
});

 $('.thumb5').click(function(){
$('iframe').attr('src', "page5.html");

});
```

With Chrome, this works on desktop/PC. On mobile however, the iframe src doesn't change but remains to be "page3.html", the content doesn't change accordingly on click with different thumbnails.
Help and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: And you're sure the click event is triggered, and that the issue is setting the source.

Comment: @adeneo, I am sure this is the case on the desktop version of Chrome since they have the desired behaviours. Would it not be the case in mobile version? Could you give some suggestion on how to access this on mobile?

Comment: Well, you can really click anything on a phone, you can tap. Make sure the `click` event really does fire when tapping on your phone

Comment: Thank you adeneo, I think this is the issue. Could you suggest a way to test if the "click" event really fire? 
I also tried to add the "tap" event to the code, however the result remains the same: 
    $(".thumb1").on("tap",function(event){
          $('iframe').attr('src',"page1.html");
          });

Comment: I added <a> tags to the thumbnails, the event is firing now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used TouchSwipe jQuery Plughin, so the "click" even is clashing with the "swipe". `<a>` tags are added to wrap around the thumbnail, and the click event is firing.